# How to check if two strings are equal in fortran?

Tags: string, fortran, strcmp

I want to check if two strings are equal and do some work.

```
character(len = 50) :: x, y ,z  
x="amin"    
y="amin"
if(llt(x, y)) then
  z=x
end if
```

I wrote this but it just checks first character in my string.
How can i handle it?

Comment: if(x < y) then ...

Comment: if (x == y) then ...

Answer (score 4):

In Fortran two strings can be compared via relational operations i.e. `<`, `>`, `==`, `/=`,  [etc.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_operators.htm).
So in your case:

```
if ( x == y ) then
  z = x 
end if
```

The `llt()` function does something completly different:

> The `llt()` function tests whether a string is lexically less than another string based on the ordering of the ASCII collating sequence.